# Lag in my Html Canvas Game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, lag

I started to make a video game with Html canvas and JavaScript: you are an alien have to shoot out other red aliens. If you come near an alien(enemy) the enemy starts to move in your direction. Now if the player comes near an Enemy, that is near another Enemy(but not as much to see the player) the game starts to lag.

This is the function of the distance and move to function:

```
this.moveto = function(vec,vel){

    distX   = vec.x - vec.offsetx - this.x
    distY   = vec.y - vec.offsety - this.y

    dist    = Math.sqrt(distX*distX + distY*distY)
    distX /= dist
    distY /= dist
    i+= 1
    if(dist >= 2){
    this.x += (distX/100)*vel
    this.y += (distY/100)*vel
    }

}

this.dist = function(vec){

    dist2X  = vec.x - vec.offsetx - this.x
    dist2Y  = vec.y - vec.offsety - this.y

    dist2   = Math.sqrt(dist2X*dist2X + dist2Y*dist2Y)

    return(dist2)

}
```

and this is how it's used:

```
for(i = 0; i < this.enemies.length; i++){

        this.enemies[i].update()

        if(this.enemies[i].dist(this.player) > 100){
            this.enemies[i].move()
        }else{

            this.enemies[i].moveto(this.player,30)

        }

        if(this.enemies[i].lives <= 0){

            this.enemies.splice(i,1)

        }

    }
```

("enemies" is an array with 5 enemies)
This is the enemy.move():

```
this.vector = new Vector(x,y,534/8,1517/8)

this.vector.move = function(){

    if(this.passi <= 2){ //1

        game.rspe.play()

        if(game.level.tick){

            this.IndexX++;

        }

        this.currentImage = game.enemyl
        this.x-=3;

        if (this.IndexX > 10){

            this.passi++
            this.IndexX = 0;

        }

    }else if(this.passi > 2 && this.passi <= 5){  //2

        game.rspe.play()

        if(game.level.tick){
            this.IndexX++;  
        }

        this.currentImage = game.enemyr
        this.x+=3;

        if (this.IndexX > 10){

            this.IndexX = 0;
            this.passi++

        }

    }else{

        this.passi = 0

    }

}

return(this.vector)
```

this is the git repository: https://github.com/Lollipopper/A1bKJBABJQ-W6-hi-jH-

Comment: I'd recommend profiling your javascript using the Chrome dev tools. There are many [videos on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=chrome+performance+profiling&page=&utm_source=opensearch) explaining how to do this. Hope you fix it! ^^

Comment: It works thanks for the advice